# Yii cactivedataprovider count duplicates record and all record count

Tags: yii

```
 $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->group = 't.blahah_id'; 
    $result = new CActiveDataProvider('SocialnetworkSpams', array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result->getData());



    Array
(
    [0] => SocialnetworkSpams Object
        (
            [total] => 
            [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 
            [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [created_date] => 2015-12-04 03:50:47
                    [feedtype] => 1
                    [feedback] => 
                    [spam_status] => 1
                    [approveby_id] => 1
                    [blahah_id] => 1
                    [bunit_id] => 3
                    [spamby_id] => 1
                )

            [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => 
            [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => 1
            [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t
            [_errors:CModel:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_validators:CModel:private] => 
            [_scenario:CModel:private] => update
            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
        )

    [1] => SocialnetworkSpams Object
        (
            [total] => 
            [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 
            [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [created_date] => 2015-12-04 04:24:07
                    [feedtype] => 5
                    [feedback] => a
                    [spam_status] => 0
                    [approveby_id] => 
                    [blahah_id] => 2
                    [bunit_id] => 3
                    [spamby_id] => 1
                )

            [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => 
            [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => 4
            [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t
            [_errors:CModel:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_validators:CModel:private] => 
            [_scenario:CModel:private] => update
            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
        )

)
```

[image]

I want duplicate record get using blahah id you can check bellow image:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks 
I have been resolved this issue.

```
  $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = '*, count(*) as total';
    $criteria->group = 't.blahah_id';
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
```

View Page :

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'spam-user-grid',
    'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'template' => "{items}{pager}",
    'pager' => array(
        'header' => '',
    ),
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'header' => 'Blahah',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'ucfirst($data->ratingprofile->name)',
        //'filter' => CHtml::textField('User[name]'),
        ),
        array(
            'header' => 'Total',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => '$data->total',
        ),

        ),
    )
));
```